# Second row of tags is not visible while editing post via Android app

Tags: bug, tags, android-app

When the total length of tags exceeds screen width, the tag's tail becomes invisible while editing the question via Android app:

> [image]

As you can see the top row of tags also is sligtly obscured.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (172342203b663)